# Regex for email address not accept '&' before 'dot'

Tags: regex

This is part of function to validate email addresses in phpbb.
I have a VALID email address

"pwd-p&r2.coop@..." but it is not accepted by the validation.

The interesting thing is that when I tried "pwd-pr2.co&op@..." (with '&' after 'dot')

and "pwd-pr&2coop@..." (without 'dot'), both are valid,

but "pwd-pr&2.coop@..." (with 'dot' after '&') is not.

I have tried to change the regex for several days but still not figure out how to fix it so that it accepts my email address.

```
function get_preg_expression($mode)
{
    switch ($mode)
    {
        case 'email':
        // Regex written by James Watts and Francisco Jose Martin Moreno
        // http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php
        return '([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*(?:[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]|&amp;)+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,63})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)';
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `&` is not a special character in regex so you do not need to escape it

Comment: I cannot confirm, for me it matches `pwd-p&r2.coop@…` as well. What regex engine do you use (what programming language)? Are there additional constraints for validation acception, apart from the regex?

Comment: @ted: No. The regex proposed there does obviously not match the OPs valid addresses. Rather have a look at http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: @Bergi, true, misunderstood the OP; deleting

Comment: @Bergi: The function is inside the "functions.php" which is included in another php file.
I think the problem here is the postion of '&' relative to 'dot' They are valid if only one of them is present or '&' behind 'dot'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function get_preg_expression($mode)
{
    switch ($mode)
    {
        case 'email':
        // Regex written by James Watts and Francisco Jose Martin Moreno
        // http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php
        // return '^(?:[\w!#$%&\'*+-\/=?^`{|}~]+\.)*(?:[\w!#$%&\'*+-\/=?^`{|}~]|&amp;)+$';
        return '(?:[\w!#$%&\'*+-\/=?^`{|}~]+\.)*(?:[\w!#$%&\'*+-\/=?^`{|}~]|&amp;)+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,63})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)';
    break;
    }
}
```

I unescaped the characters that didn't need escaping in the leading bracket expressions. That seems to have done the trick. More specifically, the only characters I left escaped were: (a) `'`, due to PHP string escape syntax, and (b) `/` because I used `/` as PHP's preg delimiter.

I don't have a theory about why this unescaping helped, unfortunately. However, it's a best practice only to escape what needs escaping, so I arrived at the solution in light of what you "should" do, so I'm comfortable sharing. The answer isn't satisfying, but at least it seems to work.

Here's the test harness I used for testing, in case it's useful, plus matchiness:

```
function get_preg_expression($mode)
{
    switch ($mode)
    {
        case 'email':
        // Regex written by James Watts and Francisco Jose Martin Moreno
        // http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php
        // return '^(?:[\w!#$%&\'*+-\/=?^`{|}~]+\.)*(?:[\w!#$%&\'*+-\/=?^`{|}~]|&amp;)+$';
        return '(?:[\w!#$%&\'*+-\/=?^`{|}~]+\.)*(?:[\w!#$%&\'*+-\/=?^`{|}~]|&amp;)+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,63})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)';
    break;
    }
}

var_dump(preg_match('/' . get_preg_expression('email') . '/', 'pwd-pr&2coop@hello.com')); // Matches
var_dump(preg_match('/' . get_preg_expression('email') . '/', 'pwd-pr&2.coop@hello.com')); // Matches
var_dump(preg_match('/' . get_preg_expression('email') . '/', 'pwd-p&r2.coop@hello.com')); // Matches
var_dump(preg_match('/' . get_preg_expression('email') . '/', 'hello')); // Does not match
var_dump(preg_match('/' . get_preg_expression('email') . '/', 'hello@world')); // Does not match
var_dump(preg_match('/' . get_preg_expression('email') . '/', 'hello@world.com')); // Matches
```

Comment: I did not see your answer a few minutes ago. I've just tested your regex. It's working very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Emails should not be validated using a regex, for exactly the reasons that are happening in this question -- it's complex, and virtually nobody gets it right.

PHP has a built-in email validator in the form of the [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) function. This is generally the best option for validating emails.

It's a one-line piece of code, without any complex regular expressions required at all.

Examples copied from the above link (ie the PHP manual):

```
<?php
$email_a = 'joe@example.com';
$email_b = 'bogus';

if (filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This (email_a) email address is considered valid.";
}
if (filter_var($email_b, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This (email_b) email address is considered valid.";
}
?>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is definitely The Right Thing for PHP in general (so +1), but will it work in the context of OP's need for phpBB? AFAIK, phpBB handles a lot of validation with regexes, so the right answer may not actually work in this case. OP, can you confirm this works for your needs?

Comment: @Spudley: It's true that filter_var() works great. I used to do that. However, I'm using the phpBB's code, so it's hard to fix everything that is already built. But thank you!

Comment: @sigpwned: You're completely correct. I'm still trying different regex to fix this.